# Hide Keyboard and secureTextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have two text fields in my login screen. And they are connected to .h files of my ViewController.

The following code is not hiding keyboard. Also, the first time I type the password, it doesn't secure text, if I tab to username again and tab back to password, then it does secure the password. But keyboard still don't go away.

Thanks

```
- (IBAction)proximoElemento:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.usuarioTextField)
    {
        [self.passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.passwordTextField)
    {
        self.passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
        [self.passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `[self.view endEditing:YES];` to hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to viewDidLoad:

`self.passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;`
This show secure password each time the passwordTextField will be active (You can set it up in storyboard as well) and remove it from your `else if` statement also when you want to hide keyboard call:

```
[self.passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
[self.passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

or call:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

In your view controller.

I don't know what proximoElemento: method supposed to do. So I don't know where you want to hide the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. But how to I set it up in storyboard?

Comment: Press on the textfield you want to make secure go to attribute inspector and there is check box 'secure', just hit on it and you don't want this line self.passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES; in your code.

Comment: Thanks, that is working. Although keyboard is still not hiding. method proximoElemento: should make next text field first responder when return key is pressed, and resign first responder at the last field. I can't figure out why it isn't working. It does work on a different app.

Comment: You should set both of the text field delegate to self: textfield.delegate = self; and try do it in -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField method instead of proximoElemento:. Remember to add <UITextFieldDelegate> protocol to your view controller.